# Office 365 and office 2013 side-by-side

Tags: windows-10, office365, microsoft-office-2013

I have a recent dell XPS 13 (i7) running windows 10 and 4K internal and external monitors.
I have noticed that some programs run very slowly when they have to use 4K screen space. Office 365 is one of them. This is a known issue which up to date a solution has not been found. I'm unsure if this solvable by running higher end hardware (eg external graphics cards)
Anyway, I have office 365 running alongside office 2013 for the simple reason that outlook 365 has some enhancements which I really appreciate (it remembers the zoom level for reading messages) and also does not go DPI crazy when I move from my external screen (which is hoked up to a Dell docking station).
Anyway, the only inconvenience I am currently finding is that no matter what I do, the default programme for opening office files (word, powerpoint, excel etc...) is office 365. Even when I go through the process of Right Click>>Open With>>Choose Another App>> and then nagivate to the office 2013 folder (office 15) and pick the 2013 version of the programme, the file will open with the respective office 365 programme! This is incredible!
Anybody know how to hack the default file associations?
Regards,
KL

Comment: The question contains a lot of information which is not needed. Could you please remove the additional information or at least make the question itself more visible? (Divide the text into paragraphs, put the additional information at the end etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows always chooses the latest installed Office as default apps to open Office files.

In other words, if you install Office 2013 at first and then install Office 365, the Office files will open with Office 365 applications instead of Office 2013 apps. Conversely, If you install Office 2013 after Office 365,  the Office files will open with Office 2013 applications.

Based on my tests, you can perform a repair for your Office 2013 and restart your computer to make Office 2013 as the default Office program:

1. In Control Panel, click **Programs > Programs and Features**, find
   your Office 2013 from the list.
2. Right-click it and select **Change**.
3. In Change your installation of Microsoft Office 2013 dialog box,
   select **Repair** and click **Continue**.
4. Wait for repairing is completed. Follow the prompt and restart your
   Windows.

Hope the information was helpful.

Best Regards,

Herb